# Вопрос о приложениях

Tags: пунктуация, синтаксис, приложение

Есть несколько предложений:

1) Когда мне было шесть лет, в книге под названием "Правдивые истории", где рассказывалось про...

2) ...есть уютное детское кафе, под названием "Утиные истории".

Почему во втором предложении приложение обособляется, а в первом — нет?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Приложение может обособляться или не обособляться в зависимости **от наличия уточняющего значения.**

В первом предложение название книги является **информацией первого плана**, автор считает важным сообщить ее название. Во втором предложение название имеет **уточняющее значение**, а главное ― это само  существование детского кафе.

Возможность обособления приложения связана и со  структурой предложения, которое строится таким образом, чтобы приложение было удобно обособить.